# MERGE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, upsert

I am trying to perform the following using a `MERGE` statement

I have a table that has two columns (`TagId` is an Identity (PK) and `Name` as a `VARCHAR`). I would like to check first if `Name` exists before I insert it. If it does exist, I would like to get the Identity value. Otherwise, I would insert it and pick up the inserted value.

The beauty of `MERGE` is it is transactional in nature. so, I won't have to worry about getting an `UNIQUE` index violation due to timing. Any suggestions? I prefer not to use transactions.

```
DECLARE 
    @TagId INT,
    @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'TagName'

SELECT TOP(1) 
  @TagId = T.TagId 
FROM dbo.Tag AS T 
WHERE T.Name = @Name 

IF @TagId IS NULL 
BEGIN
INSERT dbo.Tag (Name) VALUES (@Name)

SELECT @TagId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

After trying, this seems to work: it doesn't seem right. The `MATCHED` clause is required. Otherwise, `@Table` won't have value.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE 
(
  TagId INT,
  Name VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE 
    @TagId INT,
    @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'TdagNamed122'

MERGE dbo.Tag AS Target
USING(SELECT @Name) AS Source (Name)
  ON Source.Name = Target.Name   
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET @TagId = Target.TagId 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (Name) VALUES (Source.Name) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @Table 
;

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a transaction?

Comment: I prefer not to. Transaction would perform a lock on the table and it might be problematic.

Comment: Why would that be problematic? It's not going to be holding a lock for very long. If you want it atomic, you need a lock. Also, I'm pretty sure `merge` will be locking the table under the covers.

Comment: @Sam: if you *don't* use transactions explicitly, SQL Server will use one **implicitly**, and when updating rows, there will **always** be a lock taken ...

Comment: @marc_s, my bad: 

I was thinking that this statement will prevent that: 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

However, after reading about it, I realize that I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as per the documentation , it should execute all statements in atomic fashion
I didn't face any concurrency issues

But There are some concerns as per the link
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-cauti